# XAML Binding in binding

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I'd like to bind "MenuItemDescription"
How?

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedRessources.MenuItemDescription, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

In advance thank you

edit:

I'll try to be more explicit:
I'd like to replace "MenuItemDescription" which is currently hard coded by a string dynamicly using a binding

Sorry for my English, I use google translate to help me

Comment: please be more descriptive... anyway the first thing I think that you misspelled the LocalizedResources path. you wrote LocalizedReSSources.MenuItemDescription (double s)

Comment: I'll try to be more explicit:
I'd like to replace "MenuItemDescription" which is currently hard coded by a string dynamicly using a binding

Sorry for my English, I use google translate to help me

Comment: please post the source of LocalizedStrings resource (the binding source).

Comment: If you are looking for a way to bind to the ApplicationBar's Menu Items, then you may want to check out this project: http://phone7.codeplex.com/ it has an implementation that allows you to databind to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you either want to bind to a string defined in a Windows resource file (.resx), or you want to use a value defined in a WPF resource dictionary.

For the first case you need to bind to a static property, e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static
MyApplication:LocalizedResource.MenuItemDescription}}"/>
```

Since you can only bind to public static properties you need to change the access modifier of your LocalizedResources.resx to public (defaults to internal).  Open the resource file and you can change the access modifier.

For the second case you need to define the string in a resource dictionary (possibly app.xaml) and then use that as a static resource, e.g.:

In your dictionary

```
<System:String x:Key="MenuItemDescription">My menu item</System:String>
```

In your control

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource MenuItemDescription}"/>
```

Comment: Extra... Tank you Phil & others!