# ResourceDictionary v .resx

Tags: wpf, localization

In a WPF application, for a localizable text resource such as an error message, should I be using a .resx file or a ResourceDictionary.  If the answer is either/or what factors would help me decide which to use?

Comment: Googled upon this [WPF Localization Using RESX Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files), it gives a list of issues when localizing XAML using the Locbaml tool (that's not a tool it's a code-sample according to msdn) which answers the second part of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using .resx files - with the name of the culture in the filename - is probably the easiest way to go. The loading of the appropriate resources is handled for you.

So you'd have "ResourceFile.resx" as your default and then "ResourceFile.en-GB.resx", "ResourceFile.fr-FR.resx" etc for your localised strings.

You only need to put those strings that actually need localisation in the language files. If the string's not present in the culture specific file it falls back to the default file.

Comment: Thanks, the thing that puts me off using the .resx file is that it doesn't seem as XAML friendly, is there an easy way to reference/bind .resx resources from XAML?  I'm using MVVM so I'm thinking my ViewModel would supply resource keys

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257888/xaml-binding-in-binding/9261014#9261014 for an example of binding to properties in a .resx